# RealmObject.addChangeListener is not working if object is updated from a Service

Tags: android, realm

I have registered a single object changelistener in a fragment. What I expect is the change listener will be triggered and run `setupUI` when a notification from firebase came in and updated the same RealmObject `order` from `FirebaseCloudMessagingService`.

I tried to register `addChangeListener` using `RealmResults`, and it worked just fine (change listener is triggered and UI is updated) when a notification came in through `FirebaseCloudMessagingService`. but I only want to listen to this particular object. what am I missing ? Please Help.

```kotlin
class DeliveryInfoFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var order: Order

    companion object {
        fun instantiate(order: Order): DeliveryInfoFragment {
            val fragment = DeliveryInfoFragment()
            fragment.order = order
            return fragment
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        .....
        .....
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        order.addChangeListener(
            RealmObjectChangeListener<Order> { _, _ ->
                if (isVisible)
                    setupUI()
            }
        )
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (isVisible)
            order.removeAllChangeListeners()
    }
```